# Finding the definite integral of a product given on multiplicand's derivative?

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

So I need to find $\displaystyle\int_0^3f(x)g'(x)dx $, given that $f(x)=x^2$, and $g(x)$ satisfies the values in the table below $\left(\displaystyle\frac {d}{dx}g(x) = g'(x)\right)$.

[image]

I have tried every reasonable combination of integration by subsitution, and have tried or thought about doing integration by parts the second time, but still can't seem to figure out an answer.

EDIT: This is what I have tried:

$u=f(x), u'=f'(x)$

$v'=g'(x), v=g(x)$

$\displaystyle\int_0^3f(x)g'(x)dx=f(x)g(x)\big|_{0}^{3}-\displaystyle\int _0^3 g(x)f(x)'dx$

I can't integrate the second term on the right hand side, so by trying integration by parts again on this integral

$u=f(x), u'=f''(x)$
 and $v'=g(x), v=\displaystyle\int g(x)dx$ would require me to integrate $g(x)$. Doing it the other way round (i.e. $u=g(x), u'=g'(x)...)$ would simply take me back to square one.

Also, I am not aware of the Stieltjes integral.

Comment: can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: If you know about the Stieltjes integral then this is cake.

Comment: That depends. How does $g(x)$ behave _between_ the $x$-values in your table? If it's constant until it jumps to the next value at the next $x$ in your table, Stieltjes integral might be pertinent. If not, you'd have to interpolate between those points, but you'd have to make some assumptions about the behavior of $g(x)$.